# How to perform cummulative sum operation on inner object property value using javascript/typescript/angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to get sum of all successCount from the below array object.
var successCount;//I want count of all successCount attributes from the below object

```
var accordianData = [
  {
    name: "Start of Day",
    subItemsData: [
      {
        title: "Position",
        items: [
          { title: "XYZ",successCount:3,warningCount:1,status:"success"},
          { title: "ABC",successCount:3,warningCount:1,status:"success"},
          { title: "DDD",successCount:3,warningCount:1,status:"success"},
          { title: "ABCD",successCount:10,warningCount:1,status:"success"}
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Trades",
        items: [
          { title: "DDD",successCount:3,warningCount:0,status:"success"},
          { title: "DDD",successCount:30,warningCount:0,status:"success"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }];
```

Comment: Did you attempt something?

Comment: If you have not put any effort then you are probably not going to get anything from SO

Comment: Show the code of what you have tried so far, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general solution that will traverse your data (even of unknown structure) and sum up `successCount`s wherever they are.

```ts
const dfs = (sum: number, node: any): number =>
  typeof node === 'object' 
    ? Object.keys(node).map(key => node[key]).reduce(dfs, sum + (node['successCount'] || 0))
    : Array.isArray(node) ? node.reduce(dfs, sum) : sum

alert(dfs(0, accordianData));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var accordianData = [{name:"StartofDay",subItemsData:[{title:"Position",items:[{title:"XYZ",successCount:3,warningCount:1,status:"success"},{title:"ABC",successCount:3,warningCount:1,status:"success"},{title:"DDD",successCount:3,warningCount:1,status:"success"},{title:"ABCD",successCount:10,warningCount:1,status:"success"}]},{title:"Trades",items:[{title:"DDD",successCount:3,warningCount:0,status:"success"},{title:"DDD",successCount:30,warningCount:0,status:"success"}]}]},{name:"IntraofDay",subItemsData:[{title:"Position",items:[]},{title:"MarketData",items:[]},{title:"Trades",items:[]}]}];
  
let successCount = accordianData.reduce((a, {subItemsData}) =>
    subItemsData.reduce((ac, {items}) => 
      items.reduce((acc, v) => 
        v.status === "success" ? acc + v.successCount : acc
      , ac) 
    ,a)
  , 0);
  
  console.log(successCount);
```

Comment: @RambabuBommisetti - Glad to help you :)